# Tell a process PID by it's window?

Tags: process

How I can tell a process image name (to run from terminal using `sudo`) showing on the Ubuntu UI?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041532/getting-pid-and-details-for-topmost-window

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Per your request on the other question, here is my answer again:

> I'm sure there is a cleaner way of doing it, but for your second question you can try this:
>
> ```
>    xprop _NET_WM_PID | sed 's/_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = //' | ps `cat`
> ```
>
> This will make your cursor a cross with which you can click on an open window. It will report the PID and command in the terminal you ran it in.
>
> In general, xprop and xwininfo will provide you with a lot of information about an open window.

The "apostrophes" I used for surrounding cat are the ~ key on my keyboard without pressing shift. This should give you some more info on the subject:

[Grave Accents and the backquote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent#Use_in_programming)

Comment: xprop says:

_NET_WM_PID: not found. 

This method not foolproof enough...

Comment: This is easier to remember: `xprop | grep PID` (although it only prints the process ID)

Comment: This answer just reminded me that I already had a Cinnamon applet doing exactly this in my task bar, which I had totally forgotten about. Wow. Thanks for that at least!

Answer (score 24):

You can try `xprop | grep WM_CLASS` and then click on the window you are interested in.

Examples:

```
#> xprop | grep WM_CLASS
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gedit", "Gedit"

#> xprop | grep WM_CLASS
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gcalctool", "Gcalctool"
```

And since we need the PID, we need to do `xprop | grep PID`.

Comment: This does not return the process ID (PID). Instead, use `xprop | grep PID`.

Answer (score 13):

Run this command in a terminal:

```
xprop | awk '/PID/ {print $3}'
```

Your mouse pointer will be replaced with crosshairs; select the window you're interested in.

*This method shows just the PID of the process who owns that window (which appears to be what you want).*

Answer (score 3):

You can get process info using:

```
$ ps -f --pid $(xprop _NET_WM_PID | grep -o '[0-9]*')
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `xprop | awk '/_NET_WM_PID\(CARDINAL\)/{print $NF}'` and clicking the window you want the PID of will print the PID to the terminal.