# "Are you sure you want to proceed?" message on login

Tags: 14.04, login, elementary

I am getting the message below each time I am logging in. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

The message first appeared after I tried to install Elementary OS Pantheon session, which didn't work.
I had to completely reinstall my system, but the message keeps appearing.
Therefore, it probably created something in my home folder, but I don't know what and where to look.

Anyone got any hints? I didn't find any elementary folder in my /home.
I also checked .profile and startup applications, but nothing.

[image]

Comment: do you have the system and your home folder separate? (different partitons, disks etc.)

Comment: I'm actually more interested in the fact that you can't answer no...

Comment: they are different partitions. / was formatted on reinstall, /home was kept

Comment: look in "start up applications" for anything that might produce that.

Comment: I checked that. There is nothing that could do this.

Comment: are you logged in even if you don't click **OK**?

Comment: No, if I don't click OK it hangs there

Comment: You misread my question, I am using Ubuntu. Anyway, I figured it out.

Comment: @Fabby `I am using Ubuntu 14.04 x64 ... after I tried to install Elementary OS Pantheon session` The OP is using Ubuntu not Elementary OS ([you can install Pantheon the desktop session used on it on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/70974/178596). **Burdu** What commands did you use?

Comment: My apologies...  **:(** Close vote retracted!

Comment: Maybe you could try at least find out to what process this pop-up belongs ? Refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/137875/295286)

Comment: I solved it. See my answer below.

Comment: THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER - I do not have enough reputation here to add comments. I was having the same issue and I too utilize a script that changes the sensitivity of my wireless mouse via xinput commands. Thanks for reporting back and making StackExchange really valuable!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out after some digging. I have a script in my .profile file that changes some settings for touchpad and keyboard. I've been using it for a few years, but didn't get this error before.

Some of the commands from the script seem not to be working anymore:

```
xinput set-int-prop "VertResolution" 7
xinput set-int-prop "HorizResolution" 5
xinput --set-prop --type=float "Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4013" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration"
```

E.g.:

```
$ xinput set-int-prop "VertResolution" 7
Usage: xinput set-int-prop <device> <property> <format (8, 16, 32)> <val> [<val> ...]
```

I assume that when .profile is loaded and those errors are returned, the system pops that message, because when I run them manually, I don't get the pop-up.

Anyway, I commented them out and I don't get the message anymore.

So the source of problems was in my .profile

Comment: Thank you! For me it was .xprofile

Answer (score 3):

I got the same thing starting yesterday when I installed updates.
I found that any command in .profile that generates output causes this.
If you eliminate the output, the commands still run and this dialog doesn't appear.
For example, I had a line like this:

```
xgamma -gamma 0.7
```

I changed it to this and the mysterious dialog no longer appears:

```
xgamma -gamma 0.7 >& /dev/null
```

I don't know why this happens, it looks like a bug. But at least this makes it go away.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when upgrading to the latest Ubuntu 20.04. But I was not even able to click on the *OK* button, thus not able to login at all.

How I solved it:

1. Switched to the text console by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (switching back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>).
2. Tried to login with my username and password in the console. It indicated  an error while login (some problem with [`thefuck`](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck)).
3. I reinstalled the package and rebooted the system.
4. Problem solved!

It's probably a good idea for you to login over the text console because it may indicate the underlying problem.

Comment: You reinstalled, "the package"? Which package?

Comment: I had exactly the same issue.  In my upgrade from 18.04 it seems either pip or thefuck got removed so all I needed to do was do `pip install thefuck`.  So there is no 'package' as such